# Sending String array using multipart-formdata in Alamofire?

Tags: php, ios, alamofire, multipart

I have been doing some task about sending a String array using **multipart-formdat**a in **Alamofire** to an **Laravel** host.

My code like :

```
//End coding data.
let stringsData = NSMutableData()

for string in arrayFriend {

        if let stringData = string.email.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {

            stringsData.appendData(stringData)
        }
    }
    //Upload by form data.
    Alamofire.upload(.POST, HTDefines.WEBSERVICE.CREATE_NEW_EVENT, multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) -> Void in

        //FRIENDS
        multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: stringsData, name: HTDefines.KEY.FRIENDS)


        }) { (result) -> Void in
            switch (result) {
            case .Success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.progress { bytesRead, totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead in
                    progress(totalBytesRead: totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead: totalBytesExpectedToRead)
                }
                upload.responseJSON { response in

                    switch response.result {
                    case .Success(let JSON):

                    }
                    case .Failure(let error):
                    }
                }
            case .Failure:
                break
            }
    }
}
```

But my server has respond :

```
array_unique() expects parameter 1 to be array
```

Anyone can help me? Thank you so much.

Comment: We can't help you if you are not providing any php code

Comment: Sorry. This is my PHP Code: `$uniquiArray = array_unique($request->friends);`

Comment: Please use `var_dump($request->friends)` and check what the output is, it obviously isn't an array as the error said .

Comment: Thank you very much. I encode array using NSJSONSerialization, and decode it in PHP. I have solved it.

Comment: can you tell me how you decoded in php. i am stuck with that problem.